# javascript sometimes fails to enable/disable textarea controls

Tags: javascript

oi. i generate html and javascript for use within a c# webbrowser, and i'm debugging it with firebug via firefox.

```
function able(id,ckd) {
  if(document.getElementById) {
    var el = document.getElementById("answer"+id);
    el.disabled = ckd;
    el = document.getElementById("comment"+id);
    el.disabled = ckd;
  }
}
```

for use against

```
<html><head><style type="text/css"></style></head><body><form>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><input name="asked" id="asked1" type="checkbox" checked onchange="able('1',!this.checked);" />&nbsp;Active</td>
      <td><textarea name="answer" id="answer1">Some big, fat answer.</textarea></td>
      <td><textarea name="comment" id="comment1">Some snarky comment.</textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input name="asked" id="asked2" type="checkbox" onchange="answer2.disabled=!this.checked;comment2.disabled=!this.checked;" />&nbsp;Active</td>
      <td><textarea name="answer" id="answer2" disabled></textarea></td>
      <td><textarea name="comment" id="comment2" disabled></textarea></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <input name="save" type="button" onclick="window.external.UpdateCandidateQuestions();" value="save" />
  <input name="reset" type="reset" value="reset" />
</form></body></html>
```

the real generated html is LONG but well-formed, and i was careful to avoid cached pages while testing. the second method (asked2.onchange uses inline javascript) works less well than the first method (asked1.onchange calls javascript function defined in the head). the id counter (ie, asked"1", asked"2", asked"3", et al) and the answer and comment innertext values are either from a database or entered via webbrowser. there is a consistent fail point, and firebug walks through it as if it works, but it fails. if i remove table rows before and/or after the full data fail point, the fail point moves. once it fails, the remainder of the page fails as well.

please advise on where else i might debug this pima.

Comment: A side note, you don't really need to check for `document.getElementById` unless you're supporting some really screwy browser

Comment: yep, i can reference directly, but i'm generating the javascript call. the id suffix is based off database values with a pattern dependent on where it's sourced from - ie, an answered or unanswered question. thx tho. i am supporting a really screwy browser - internet explorer.

Answer (score 0):

It is rarely a good idea to use the *change* event with radio buttons. According to the W3C HTML 4.01 specification the [onchange](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/scripts.html#adef-onchange) event:

> ...occurs when a control loses the
>   input focus and its value has been
>   modified since gaining focus. 
>   http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/scripts.html#adef-onchange

IE works that way for all form controls - you need to modify the control, then click elsewhere to make it lose focus so a change event is dispatched (if the state changed). Other browsers will dispatch a change event if a click changes a button's status, it doesn't need to lose focus.

It is much better to user an onclick listener and do some action based on whether the control is checked or not.

The above may or may not fix your issue. As far as I can see, there is no reason why the *able()* function should not work, just change `onchange` to `onclick`.

Comment: i originally used the onclick event, but it was not picking up the modified value of the checkbox. however, all kinds of things were wonked, and when i rebooted the pc the next day, all kinds of other problems magically went away. i <3 javascript, et al. i'll reinstate as onclick again and have a look-see, thx.

Comment: no dice. same error. there's gotta be a bad character from the database harking up the html.